# My HTML form only returns 1 value into the PHP mail

Tags: php, html, forms

The email I receive only shows the message, not the email address or phone number or even the name.

It also doesn't show from which email it has been sent.

I should receive whole information from the form, otherwise it wouldn't show me the message, I guess.

Maybe someone has more simple code than this one?

I tried but I'm stuck.

Can someone help me out?

Below is the HTML and PHP code

HTML Code:

```
<form name="mail"  action="mail.php" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
                    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
                    <input id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" type="text" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send Message" name="submit" type="submit">
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

PHP code:

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
  echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];



$email_from = "$email";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_phone = $phone;
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user ".$name.
    "\nHere is the message:\n ".$message.
    "\nThe phone number:\n ".$phone.
    "The email:\n ".$email.
    
$to = "info@czwebdesign.be";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: index.html');



?>
```

Comment: because u r only using NAME attribute for message field `name="message"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here at the missing `name=""` attribute in your `<input>` 
Use this code instead:

```
<form name="mail"  action="mail.php" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
                    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
                    <input name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" type="text" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send Message" name="submit" type="submit">
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Wow I feel stupid now for not seeing that, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use `name` attribute for other fields as well same like `message` field, something like:

```
<input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
<input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAme" required>
<input name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
```

> Otherwise you will get the Undefined Index warning in your script.

*It's better to use php [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in your development mode, this will help to find out all errors and warnings in your code.*

```
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: or he can use whoops for nice displaying from [here](https://filp.github.io/whoops/)

Comment: @Blueblazer172: ahan ... :)

Comment: @Blueblazer172: and i am 100% sure, OP next question is my email is not working on localhost... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<form name="mail"  action="mail.php" method="post" >
            <div class="form-group ">
                <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name" required>
                <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send Message" name="submit" type="submit">
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: it's better to add some explanation